# it (x in dots) takes only some vectors

Tags: r

I think that this (x in dots) takes only some vectors. I'll be glad for any help. These vectors are only example.

```
m<-c(2,5,6,9,7,5,8,4)
s<-c(5,5,4,2)
t<-c(6,9,7,8)
g1 <- function(z, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  for (x in dots) p<- (sum((x - mean(x))^2)/sum((z - mean(z))^2))
  return(p) }
g1(m, s, t)
```

vector s and t are only example. their number is variable. and I have to use (sum((x - mean(x))^2)/sum((z - mean(z))^2)). This is from t and s. the first vector (m in this example) is in this section sum((z - mean(z))^2))
for example without function:

```
s1 <- (s - mean(s))^2
t1<- (t - mean(t))^2 
p1 ..........
m1 <- (m - mean(m))^2

(sum(s1)+sum(t1)+sum(p1)+.....)/sum(m1)
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @jogo, looks like I need a coffee. I will delete my answer, post yours.

Comment: Maybe: `sapply(list(s, t), function(x) { sum((x - mean(x))^2)/sum((m - mean(m))^2) })`?

Comment: @Chillls.s: would be really good to see numbers you are looking for.

Comment: it true, thanks. But what if the vectors will be more, not only s and t?? It change the first section sum(sapply(list(s, t), sd) and it is what i need.

Comment: You need to give them somewhere, either in list(s, t, all_the_rest) or in you function's call - I don't see much difference here.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
myvar <- function(x) sum((x-mean(x))^2)
sum(sapply(list(s, t), myvar)) / myvar(m)

#> m<-c(2,5,6,9,7,5,8,4)
#> s<-c(5,5,4,2)
#> t<-c(6,9,7,8)
#> myvar <- function(x) sum((x-mean(x))^2)
#> sum(sapply(list(s, t), myvar) / myvar(m))
#[1] 0.3098592
```